# Extracting the id of an element from Event Listener e.path Array?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I’m trying to get my head around Event’s and I’m totally lost? I would like to access an elements id from an event listener, using `e.path` Array? The id that I want is always in the article `id=”someID”` node of the `objTmp Array()`.

I also can figure out why this only works in Chrome all other browsers say that `objTmp` is undefined?

Any help would be appreciated...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Working </title>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function init() {

            var eventTmp = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
            for (var i = 0; i < eventTmp.length; i++) {
                eventTmp[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    var objTmp = e.path;
                    for (var i = 0; i < objTmp.length; i++) {
                        
                        if (objTmp[i].tagName === "ARTICLE") {
                            //This is where I get lost
                            //How do I get the id from this node??
                            var x = objTmp[i];
                            console.log(x);
                        }
                    }
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }, false);

            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <main id="">
        <article id="id_Article0">
            <section>
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                        <li>Link 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
        <article id="id_Article1">
            <section>
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <h3>Some Text</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Link 1</li>
                            <li>Link 2</li>
                            <li>Link 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Auto complete is not always your friend... it didn't offer id as an option.

I was able to get the id using:

var x = objTmp[i].id;
console.log(x);

But I still can't figure out why only Chrome works all other browsers say that objTmp is undefined??

Comment: event.path is a Chrome-only nonstandard event property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to locate the ancestor ARTICLE node without using event.path:

```
function init() {

    var eventTmp = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    for (var i = 0; i < eventTmp.length; i++) {
        eventTmp[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          var articleNode = this;
          while (articleNode.nodeName != "ARTICLE" && articleNode.nodeName != "BODY") {
            articleNode = articleNode.parentNode;
          }
          if (articleNode.nodeName == "BODY") {
            // no article ancestor was found
          } else {
            // do something with articleNode
            console.log(articleNode.id);
          }

          e.stopPropagation();
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive had better luck with:

```
e.target.id
```

If there's multiple targets then:

```
e.target[i].id
```

A bigger problem Im seeing is that both your outter for loop and your nested for loop have the same counter variable `i`.
You'd want to give the inner for loop a different counter variable.